# HystrixCommand annotation causes Session closed errors

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, hystrix

I have a spring app that I'm trying to use the Circuit Breaker pattern on via Hystrix. I marked a method in my service with the `@HystrixCommand` annotation. This method has a call to a repository that works fine without the `@HystrixCommand` annotation.

However, simply adding the annotation gives me a bunch of runtime exceptions - org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed! and java.net.ConnectException. I don't understand enough about `@HystrixCommand` or spring to really understand what's going on here. Is there something about my repository connection I need to know before using Hystrix? I basically have just followed the guide here: https://spring.io/guides/gs/circuit-breaker/

Appreciate any feedback or leads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add the following config to your properties/yml file

```
hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.strategy: SEMAPHORE
```

[Here is some documentation for further reading](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/Configuration#execution.isolation.strategy)

Comment: With this change hystrix will use the same thread for execution -> so there is no possibility to force a timeout. Only the possible parallel requests can be limited.